# Need a efficient query way to calculate sum of work days in snowflake(without using function)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dimensions, snowflake-schema

I have a `Date Dimension` which has the date column( having dates from 2010 to 2020) along with the `Isworkday` bit column (which is either 0 or 1). All the holidays are calculated and pre-populated in the dimension.

Now, I have a table which gives the `start_date` and `end_date`columns and I need to calculate the `sum_of_workdays` in those two date ranges using the date dimension.

(I know I can create a function which accepts start date and end date and returns sum of work days using date dimension but snowflake is really inefficient with functions hence i want to do with sub queries or joins or anything)

This is the function i currently use:

```
create or replace function Sum_Of_WorkDays(start_date TIMESTAMP, end_date TIMESTAMP)
  returns int 
  as--to get sume of workdays in a given date range
  $$
    SELECT sum(ISWORKDAY) 
    FROM DATE_DIMENSION 
    WHERE "DATE" BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
  $$
  ;
```

And below is how am calling the function from the table to calculate sum but takes lot of time if there are joins and cte involved in the query::

```
select Sum_Of_WorkDays(start_date,end_date) from table
```

Any efficient query for it other than using a function?

Conclusion: Ended up using Left join for each sum calculations to optimize it. Snowflake apparently sometimes is not that good in query optimization.

Comment: Can you share your code where this function interacts with the CTEs and joins you mention? I think your goal with the function can be just as easily achieved using an uncorrelated subquery, at least for the example you shared

Comment: I know you are suggesting to directly add a query in the column section. 
```select *,(SELECT sum(ISWORKDAY) 
    FROM DATE_DIMENSION 
    WHERE "DATE" BETWEEN START_DATE AND end_DATE)
             ) column1 from table1```

This is essential the same as function. I have checked and both take the same time to run. Problem is that in place of table1, I have a huge cte which takes 2 minutes to load. And each time i use sum of workdays func in a column, snowflake is recalculating the whole cte for every row. (like if i use the func one time it takes 9 min, 2 times it takes 18 min and so on).

Comment: I would use a temp table instead, or even a perm one if the output of that CTE is relatively static and will get queried frequently

Comment: unfortunately, I need all this in a view. so temp tables out of question.
I did try using permanent table but snowflake still takes lot of time. Not sure why. I guess internally it handles subqueries in an efficient way while getting data from my date dimension. This is why i wanted to know if there is a better way to join to date dimension.